# KrakenD returns a 500 when the body of the backend endpoint doesnt have any data

Tags: go, salesforce, gateway, krakend

I am using KrakenD to make a call to a Salesforce endpoint
`/services/data/v56/jobs/ingest/{{_jobId}}/batches`

This `backend endpoint` doesn't return any data in the response body and as a result the call fails with a 500. From the logs -

`[00] [KRAKEND] 2023/01/27 - 23:39:45.615 ▶ ERROR [ENDPOINT: /ingest/:jobId/batches] EOF`

How do I solve this error? How can I tell KrakenD to expect the empty response body?
I am not using any custom plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the encoding defined at the backend section (by default, it's JSON) and select one that suits your backend responses. Here you'll find some recommendations: https://www.krakend.io/docs/backends/supported-encodings/#how-to-choose-the-backend-encoding

If you are expecting empty responses, you could use `no-op` (https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/no-op/)